# Android Scanner Read Until a Delimiter (UseLimiter)

Tags: java, c#, android, delimiter

I have a server that send a big string. I want to stop read when I i see that final delimiter.

Android:

```
 protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {


    Socket socket = null;

    try {
        socket = new Socket(dstAddress, dstPort);

        Scanner r = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

        while (true) {


            //MASTER
            valores[0] = r.nextLine();
            valores[1] = r.nextLine();
            valores[2] = r.nextLine();
            valores[3] = r.nextLine();
            valores[4] = r.nextLine();
            valores[5] = r.nextLine();
            valores[6] = r.nextLine();
            valores[7] = r.nextLine();
            valores[8] = r.nextLine();
            valores[9] = r.nextLine();
            valores[10] = r.nextLine();
            valores[11] = r.nextLine();
            valores[12] = r.nextLine();

            //SLAVE
            valores[13] = r.nextLine();
            valores[14] = r.nextLine();
            valores[15] = r.nextLine();
            valores[16] = r.nextLine();
            valores[17] = r.nextLine();
            valores[18] = r.nextLine();
            valores[19] = r.nextLine();
            valores[20] = r.nextLine();
            valores[21] = r.nextLine();
            valores[22] = r.nextLine();
            valores[23] = r.nextLine();
            valores[24] = r.nextLine();
            valores[25] = r.nextLine();

            r.useDelimiter("\\zfish");
            while (r.hasNext()) {
                valores[26] = r.next();
            }

            publishProgress(valores[0], valores[1], valores[2], valores[3], valores[4], valores[5], valores[6], valores[7], valores[8], valores[9], valores[10], valores[11], valores[12],
                    valores[13], valores[14], valores[15], valores[16], valores[17], valores[18], valores[19], valores[20], valores[21], valores[22], valores[23], valores[24], valores[25], valores[26]);
        }

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();

    } finally {
        if (socket != null) {
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    return null;

}
```

Server C#

```
            string conetado, bateria, tensao, altitude, roll, pitch, yaw, velx, vely, velz, estado, atual, desejado;
            string conetado2, bateria2, tensao2, altitude2, roll2, pitch2, yaw2, velx2, vely2, velz2, estado2, atual2, desejado2;

            conetado = master.sconetado;
            bateria = master.sbateria;
            tensao = master.stensao;
            altitude = master.saltitude;
            roll = master.sroll;
            pitch = master.spitch;
            yaw = master.syaw;
            velx = master.svelx;
            vely = master.svely;
            velz = master.svelz;
            estado = master.sestado;
            atual = master.satual;
            desejado = master.sdesejado;


            conetado2 = slave.sconetado;
            bateria2 = slave.sbateria;
            tensao2 = slave.stensao;
            altitude2 = slave.saltitude;
            roll2 = slave.sroll;
            pitch2 = slave.spitch;
            yaw2 = slave.syaw;
            velx2 = slave.svelx;
            vely2 = slave.svely;
            velz2 = slave.svelz;
            estado2 = slave.sestado;
            atual2 = slave.satual;
            desejado2 = slave.sdesejado;

            string_master_frame = Convert.ToBase64String(sendBytes);

            data = conetado + "\n" + bateria + "\n" + tensao + "\n" + altitude + "\n" + roll + "\n" + pitch + "\n" + yaw + "\n" + velx + "\n" + vely + "\n" + velz + "\n" + estado + "\n" + atual + "\n" + desejado + "\n" +
                        conetado2 + "\n" + bateria2 + "\n" + tensao2 + "\n" + altitude2 + "\n" + roll2 + "\n" + pitch2 + "\n" + yaw2 + "\n" + velx2 + "\n" + vely2 + "\n" + velz2 + "\n" + estado2 + "\n" + atual2 + "\n" + desejado2 + "\n" + string_master_frame + "fish";

            send(data)
```

My Android code is not working. it's stuck on   value = r.next(); Never leaves this line. So that means it's not looking for the fish

Answer (score 1):

Don't call r.useDelimiter() over and over in a loop!
Also how do you break out of your loop if it's set to true?!

```
    Scanner r = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    r.useDelimiter("\\s*fish\\s*"); // to find " fish " with space

    while (r.hasNext()) {
        value = r.next();
    }
    r.close(); // very important
```

Comment: edited. Why I cant use the while loop? That way is always reading and updating the TextViews right? Why would I need to close the connection everytime I read?

Comment: You have to break out of the loop somewhere that's why it's stuck as you say. Otherwise it will run indefinitely!

Comment: I had while(true) until now and It was working well. I'm stuck on while (r.hasNext()) {
        value = r.next();
    }

Comment: what do you mean by stuck?

Comment: your code is not working. Do I need to change to " fish " on the server? Include the spaces?

Comment: It never reaches the publishprogress. It was working until I introduced this new while.

Comment: I was trying to readLine like the rest. But it's a encoded image String64 and it has \n inside the string so it didnt get all the data.

Comment: So I'm trying to use Delimiter to get the last string until the end.

Comment: It's an asynctask. After it gets the data it updates the Textviews with the incomming data. That data is always changing that's why there is the while(true). I dont need to close the conection.

Comment: oh ok now i understand

Comment: Let me ask you why do you have valores[26] = r.next();

Comment: why do you use \n?

Comment: My bad that wasn't it, but could you answer my question